# Handle NULL values for integer field in a function

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have created a function to insert/update record in a table. 
Data is passed to function as arguments.
Facing problem in handling Integer/float/double fields. For example,
i have declared Empno field as Int(as per target table structure).
So i thought when a null value comes i convert into '0' using cast function. 
But its not even accepting NULL values since its declared as Int.
should i change the declaration to varchar and then convert ?
What should i do ? Please help

Error i'm getting is operator does not exist: text integer 42883

Sample CODE:

```
create function test (text[])  
declare  
companycode varchar(4);  
empno varchar(10);  
begin  
L_1 := $1[1];  
L_2 :=cast(NULLIF($1[2],0) as int);  
update and insert statement ...  
end;
```

Comment: Hi, could you please post the code for the function you've written?

Comment: Casting does not convert NULLs to zero.

Comment: updated with sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NULLIF()` changes the specified value to `NULL`, not vica-versa. Use `IFNULL()` or `COALESCE()` instead.

Also Change the order of the operations to CAST first, something like this:

```
COALESCE($1[2]::int, 0)
```

Comment: Hi Usagi, 
Thank you for your support. I tried your suggestion for another float field(replaced int with float(8)) but i'm getting another error when i try to insert: 
column is of type double precision but expression is of type character varying
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Hey Usagi,
I managed to resolve the issue. Thank you for your timely response !